# Can't run Titan/DynamoDB sample

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases, titan

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html#Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.title

I did follow step by step

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Connected - localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> com.amazon.titan.example.MarvelGraphFactory.load(graph, 100, false)
No such property: com for class: Script2
Display stack trace? [yN] y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: No such property: com for class: Script2
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:101)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:254)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:119)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:94)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:130)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:150)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:82)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:144)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:303)


(titan) ➜  dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.0-hadoop1 git:(1.0.0) ✗ java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)
```

1. Gremlin server is up & running
2. DynamoDB local is up and running
3. I'm in exact folder as defined by documentation when I run all the commands
4. I see that Marvel code exists

   (titan) ➜  dynamodb-titan-storage-backend git:(1.0.0) ✗ find . -iname 'Marvel*' 
   ./src/main/java/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory.java
   ./src/main/resources/META-INF/marvel.csv
   ./target/classes/META-INF/marvel.csv
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory$Appeared.class
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory.class
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory$ComicBookCreationCommand.class
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory$BatchCommand.class
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory$AppearedCommand.class
   ./target/classes/com/amazon/titan/example/MarvelGraphFactory$CharacterCreationCommand.class
   (titan) ➜  dynamodb-titan-storage-backend git:(1.0.0) ✗ pwd
   /home/dmitry/code/experiments/titan/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend
   (titan) ➜  dynamodb-titan-storage-backend git:(1.0.0) ✗

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into same problem. I can do `import com.amazon.janusgraph.example.MarvelGraphFactory` without problems, but if I try to do the `com.amazon.titan.example.MarvelGraphFactory.load(graph, 100, false)` it gives me the `RemoteException: No such property: com..` :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please try the Marvel walkthrough on the [updated version of the plugin here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-titan-storage-backend/tree/master#load-a-subset-of-the-marvel-universe-social-graph).